# Difference between Observable.defer and Observable.create in java rx

Tags: java, reactivex

Can someone explain me the difference between `defer` and `create` methods in `Observable`? I failed to understand when I should use `defer` and when should I use `create` ..

REFERENCES:

Defer: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defer.html

Create: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/create.html

Thank you

Answer (score 33):

So the distinction seems to be: `defer` is good when you have something that creates/returns an observable already, but you don’t want that process to happen until subscription.

`create` is good when you need to manually wrap an async process and create an observable. That creation is *also* deferred until subscription.

To put it another way:

`defer` is an operator that enables deferred composition of observable sequences.

`create` is a custom implementation of observable sequence (where creation is deferred until subscription).

So if you have a situation where you might use `just` to create an `Observable` from some results/value or you have a network API layer that returns an `Observable` of the request, but you don't want that request to kick off until subscription. `defer` would be good for those scenarios.

If you have a network API layer that *doesn't* return an `Observable` for a request, but which you need an `Observable` interface to, you might use `create`. That `Observable` sequence still wouldn't be created until subscription though. If you wanted that network call to kick off regardless of subscription, then you would use a different mechanism, like a `Subject`, potentially that replays.

Answer (score 20):

create(...) actually creates Observable immediately.

```
    public final static <T> Observable<T> create(OnSubscribe<T> f) {
        return new Observable<T>(hook.onCreate(f));
    }
```

defer(...) accepts Factory function  that returns Observable(Subject, etc...), wraps it with OnSubscribeDefer and creates Observable only when subscriber subscribes, new Observable for every subscriber.

```
public final static <T> Observable<T> defer(Func0<Observable<T>> observableFactory) {
    return create(new OnSubscribeDefer<T>(observableFactory));
}
```

See some more details [here](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/07/23/deferring-observable-code-until-subscription-in-rxjava/)

Comment: _create(...) actually creates Observable immediately._

Seems to directly contradict other answers and Dan's post you linked to.

Comment: This is incorrect. Try it out.`create` only executes its factory on subscription. So `deferred` is essentially a convenience when `create` is too cumbersome. They behave exactly the same way including creating another stream for every subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Another take on the really good answers already above — by way of an example.

Say that you have a class that returns an Observable based on its internal state(written in a pseudo Javascript like language, but applies to all ReactiveX implementations)

```
class DownloadManager {

  var uuid = nil  // this only gets set during runtime...say when a user performs a certain action

  // fetches some data from the server.
  func get() -> Observable<Data> {
    if uuid == nil {
      return .error(new DownloadUuidEmptyError())
    }
 
    return network.download(uuid, ...) // do something with the non nil uuid
  }
}
```

Written this way, the method might be called, and the observable passed around before it actually gets evaluated, and uuid might not be present at time of method call, but present by the time the Observable is subscribed to, yielding an error.

```
let observable = manager.get()

// ... at some point, uuid is assigned to
// then we subscribe to our observable ...

observable.subscribe(...).disposedBy(bag) // errors!
```

In this situation, defer can come in handy to ensure that the evaluation(of uuid, for example) does not happen until subscription time.

```
  // fetches some data from the server.
  func get() -> Observable<Data> {
    return Observable.defer {
      if uuid == nil {
        return .error(new DownloadUuidEmptyError())
      }

      return network.download(uuid, ...) // do something with the non nil uuid
    }
  }
```

Now, the above example will no longer error out. Perhaps the bigger goal is to ensure that your code can never reach this state, but sometimes it is not practical. This pattern has come in handy for me.